# How to create highlighter option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I am working in an app where I need to provide an option so that the user can highlight text.

Like this

[image]

To make text selectable, we can use the **SelectableText** widget but SelectableText widget does not have any callback to get the selected text. And using SelectableText.rich we can highlight some portion of text.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the toolbarOptions in SelectableText?

```
toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, selectAll: false),
```

Comment: This will enable feature like copy option